# Wrong charset from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

When I want to printout the output of jQuery AJAX, which has been recived from server. It doesn't show the right charset. What I want exactly is to get `š` instead I am getting `?` or without using `utf8_decode()` when sending data from server, I get `ĹĄ`. All files `script.js` and server php `proceed.php` are saved in UTF-8 and set in UTF-8. Database is set to UTF-8 as well. All other request from database give the right charset. I've tried most of the things.
In `.js` file for AJAX:

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    url: "proceed.php", //file to procces data
    ContentType : 'charset=UTF-8', // tried here
    global: false,
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "html" // change to text/html, application/text doesnt work at all
});
```

In `.php` file:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$output = utf8_decode($sql_result);
```

All possible combinations.

**CODE:**
PHP

```
if(!empty($_POST['select_had'])){
$zem = $_POST['select_had'];
$vysledek = mysql_query("SELECT typ_hadanky, jazyk FROM hlavolam RIGHT JOIN hadanka ON hlavolam.id_hlavolamu=hadanka.id_hlavolamu WHERE zeme_puvodu='$zem'");
$out = "";
while ($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array($vysledek)) {
    $zaz = $zaznam['jazyk'];
    $out .= "<option>".$zaz."</option>";
}
$vys = utf8_decode($out);
echo $vys;
```

}

jQuery:

```
$("#sel_had_zem").change(function(){
var select_had = $("#sel_had_zem option:selected").text();
$.ajax({
  data:{'select_had':select_had},
  success: function(data){
      $("#sel_had_jaz option").nextAll().remove();
      $("#sel_had_jaz").append(data);
  },
  error: function(){
      alert('No server response');
  }
 });

});
```

Comment: And this in the page? `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: You are calling `utf8_decode()` but you claim that all your stack uses UTF-8; you don't even mention ISO-8859-1. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @mplungjan That one is included already, forgot to mention

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I was trying to call that function as a desperate move, at least I got `?` instead of `ĹĄ`. With no other change to better.

Comment: Also verify your files are saved in ``UTF-8`` too

Comment: @ins0 All of them are, I've checked that several times already, because I m getting crazy

Comment: You should use UTF-8 encode while inserting data into database as well. It seems you entered the data directly into database and extracting it using UTF-8 (`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`) . So insert the data into database using query itself.

Comment: Well... Pick a sample character, make sure you know its correct encoding as UTF-8 and diagnose each step to find out where it gets corrupted. You'll probably need to print an hexadecimal dump.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález there is definetly problem in proccesing the data with AJX, though there is not many points where to test. I know that when sending data from server, they are ok, when received by jQuery.AJAX and then printed in console, they are corrupted

Comment: Any relevant information the "Net" pane?

Comment: That thing is silent as never